# Display tags cloud from a specific category ID with a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, tags

I'm trying to display some tags cloud in different locations of my Wordpress. I'm using a shortcode but I'm looking for a way to display only the tags from a specific category ID by adding this ID right in the shortcode like:

```
 [tagscloud cat_id='2']
```

I made this but I'm stuck because I don't know how to filter/apply (not sure about the right term) the cat_id.

```
function wp_tags_cloud_shortcode($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat_id' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $content = wp_tag_cloud( array( 
    'echo'      => false,
    'smallest'  => 10,
    'largest'   => 10,
    'unit'      => 'px',
    'number'    => 0,
    'format'    => 'flat',
    'orderby'   => 'count' ) 
    );
    return $content;    
}
add_shortcode( 'tagscloud', 'wp_tags_cloud_shortcode' );
```

I'm a beginner with php so any help will be much appreciate :)

Comment: you mean tag related to post inside this category ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm displaying a list of all post from a specific category and I'd like to display a tags cloud in the sidebar of that page.

Comment: In your shortcode, you're using `cat`, in the function, you're looking for `cat_id`. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a working solution :

```
function tag_cloud_shortcode($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $query_args = array( 'cat' => $atts, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
                }
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
    $tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

    $args = array(
    'echo'      => false,
    'smallest'  => 10,
    'largest'   => 10,
    'unit'      => 'px',
    'number'    => 0,
    'format'    => 'flat',
    'order'     => 'count',
    'include'   => $tags_str
    );
    return wp_tag_cloud($args);
}
add_shortcode( 'tagscloud', 'tag_cloud_shortcode' );
```

Now I can use this shortcode with multiple category ID

```
[tagscloud cat=3,5]
```

Thanks to [Jon Yablonski's post](https://jonyablonski.com/2015/category-specific-tags-list-in-wordpress/), [Nate Beers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148975/2734491) and [code.tutsplus.com](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-categories-and-tags--cms-23070)