# How to exclude labels from certain categories in a shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode, tags

Good afternoon. There is a shortcode [alltags] that displays ALL site tags on a separate page of the site in alphabetical order with a letter.

```php
function wph_alltags_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    $posttags = get_tags();
    $output = '';
    if ( $posttags ) {
        $output = '<dl class="alltags">';
        foreach ( $posttags as $tag ) {
            $l = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $tag->name, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8' );
            if ( $L != $l ) {
                if ( $L )
                    $output .= '</dd>';
                $L = $l;
                $output .= '<dt>' . $L . '</dt><dd>';
            }
            $output .= '<a href="/tag/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a> '; 
        }
        $output .= '</dl>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'alltags', 'wph_alltags_shortcode' );
```

I need to exclude the display of tags from certain categories of the site, at least from one. I am completely new to PHP. (Please help me with solving this problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've fixed the indentation and a PHP warning in the code via my edit but I'm unsure how you intend to specify which tags are to be removed? Tags don't have child/parent tags, and your code does not display categories, and tags do not have categories so your question doesn't make much sense, or something is missing that you're assuming is obvious. Can you edit your question to make it clearer and easier to understand/less ambiguous? Bonus points if you include examples. Also where did you get this code from?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the code on this site: https://www.wphook.ru/look/all-tags-in-alphabet-order.html. Tags can be removed by category id. I also found an example where this is done: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289393/display-tags-cloud-from-a-specific-category-id-with-a-shortcode. In this shortcode, tags are sorted like this: [tagscloud cat=3,5]. But I don't understand how to sort by category id in the first code. Or how to display labels alphabetically in the second shortcode.

Comment: You can't. Tags don't belong to categories. If you want a list of tags that are not assigned to posts that are assigned to certain categories you will need an SQL query. But there is almost certainly a better approach. Why do you need to exclude certain categories? What's the criteria? You might be better off using a third taxonomy that is only applied where you want it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How then is it done in this shortcode?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289393/display-tags-cloud-from-a-specific-category-id-with-a-shortcode
Using [tagscloud cat=3,5] I only get tags from categories with id=3 and id=5. All others are not displayed.

Comment: @mEdvEd you're mixing up categories and tags, the phrase "get tags from categories" doesn't make sense, tags are not categories, categories are not tags. Please make sure to use specific official terminology to avoid confusion. Nothing in your code snippet uses categories, your code _only_ uses tags. The question you linked to has a completely different shortcode that only deals with categories, not tags. What you currently have, is a shortcode that displays all **tags** belonging to the current post, so it already excludes all categories because it does not display categories.

Comment: Did you actually mean _how do I exclude tags?_

Comment: I understand that categories and tags are completely different things. I don't mix them. Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I need to exclude the output of tags from all posts included in one specific category by its id. And so that from the posts included in the remaining headings, tags are displayed on the page.

Comment: "The question you linked to has a completely different shortcode that only deals with categories, not tags." However, this shortcode only renders post tags from the categories listed here:
[tagscloud cat=3,5]

Comment: Tags and Categories are two different taxonomies. They are coding wise almost identical, but categories can have parent-child relationship (hierarchical) where tags don't. You can either get all tags or tags assigned to specific posts.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, there is no such thing as a "tag in a category", and if the current post is in the category you want to exclude, then so would all its tags, so no tags would be displayed. Can you explain in clearer more specific/detailed terms with examples? Use the edit link on the question to update it so the information is not hidden in the comments. _Be very precise with the words you use to avoid confusion_. What are you trying to build using this shortcode?

Comment: Good afternoon. Thank you for your replies. Earlier I already wrote that I expressed myself somewhat inaccurately. By tags from a certain category, I meant the tags of all posts from that category.

Comment: For example, the site has 3 categories: "Ornamental Shrubs" with ID - 3421, "Vegetables" with ID - 3422 and "Fruit Trees" with ID - 3423. There are 240 posts in the "Fruit Trees" category. Each of them has its own labels. I want all the tags of these posts in the "Fruit Trees" category not to show up on the tags page. And only post tags from the categories "Ornamental shrubs" and "Vegetable crops" were displayed on it. Those. it is necessary to add to the shortcode the ability to exclude the display of post tags belonging to a certain category. For example, by its ID.

Comment: Maybe that would make it clearer?